# In Puerto Rico If only one prospector is chosen during a round, does the other one get a coin placed on it?

Tags: puerto-rico

If only one prospector is chosen during a round, does the other one get a coin placed on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

**Any** role not chosen at the end of the round gets a coin placed on it.

I can't find the official rules online, but I can point you to the [Universal Head rules summary](http://boardgamegeek.com/file/download/2fdktaeg63/PuertoRico_v1.1.pdf), which says, under "Reset the Roles":

> Place one doubloon on each of the three role cards not
>   chosen this round and then return all role cards.

Comment: @John Robertson - But there will be one Prospector role card in a player's possession and one Prospector role card not chosen - one of three. The Prospector role card a player took will obviously not receive a doubloon, but the unchosen card **will**.

Comment: The card is the role. The two prospector cards are different roles, they just happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**,

From the [rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_4_gameRules.pdf), pg7 under "A new round ..."

> Now, the governor takes three doubloons from the bank, placing one each on the three role cards that were not selected during the round.

Answer (score 1):

Although "prospector" seems like one role, there are two people playing it. Call them prospector 1 and prospector 2.

If prospector 1 is chosen for the current round and prospector 2 isn't, prospector 2 will get a coin placed on him. Meaning that he will be chosen the next time someone needs a prospector.

The prospectors were inserted in the game as a "mechanic" to keep the number of agents greater than the number of players by three. There are no prospectors in a three person game, one in a four person game, and two in a five person game.